# How to ignore null values when reading from a form?

Tags: java, forms, null

I have the following block of code in my Java program:

```
Filter.sitesToBeFiltered.add(eid.getSite());
System.out.println("Entity Site added to ArrayList. ");

Filter.applicationsToBeFiltered.add(eid.getApplication());
System.out.println("Entity Application added to ArrayList. ");

Filter.IDsToBeFiltered.add(eid.getEntity());
System.out.println("Entity ID added to ArrayList");

Filter.positionsToBeFilteredX.add(position.getX());
System.out.println("Entity X position added to ArrayList. ");

Filter.positionsToBeFilteredY.add(position.getY());
System.out.println("Entity Y position added to ArrayList. ");

Filter.positionsToBeFilteredZ.add(position.getZ());
System.out.println("Entity Z position added to ArrayList. ");
```

Currently, it will read the values of a set of JTextFields, and add each value to an associated ArrayList. (The ArrayLists are either ArrayLists of Integers or Doubles). However, it will read their values no matter whether the value is a String, int/ double or null...

I want to add some error checking code, so that it will only add the value to the associated ArrayList if it is of the correct data type. I've tried doing this by surrounding each of the two-line blocks in the code displayed above with an 'if' statement, such as:

```
if(eid.getSite() != null){
    Filter.sitesToBeFiltered.add(eid.getSite());
    System.out.println("Entity Site added to ArrayList. ");
}
```

But if I do this, I get a compile error on the `if` statement that says "The operator != is undefined for the argument type(s) int, null"... Why is this? What should I use to check that the value of the JTextFields are not equal to `null` instead?

Comment: I think you got confused in null, empty, and 0s. An empty or 0 is not null also to mention primitive datatypes can not be null, your eid.getSite() returns `int` which will never be null. If you want it to be checked against null set its return type to `Integer` instead of int.

Comment: ArrayList in Java implements List interface and allow null. Important issue is how can you define your arraylist? Can you share your arraylist implementation code?

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
if(eid != null && eid.getSite()) {
   doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is `int` (primitive type) you will always get 0 if no value is set.
If for 0 nothing is assigned at UI side, then try to ignore zero `if (!eid.getSite() == 0)` but please make sure that 0 dont have any meaning.
With `string` you can cast return object to `string` if it's `Object` class, and check for not blank

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by adding the error checking code to where I was reading the values in from the `JTextFields`. So instead of:

```
filter1Type = String.valueOf(Gui.filter1.getSelectedItem());
filter1Value = Integer.parseInt(Gui.filter1Text.getText());
```

I now have:

```
filter1Type = String.valueOf(Gui.filter1.getSelectedItem());
if(isNumeric(Gui.filter1Text.getText()){
    filter1Value = Integer.parseInt(Gui.filter1Text.getText());
} else {
    filter1Value = 0;
    //Display some error message to the user here.
}
```

So now, any value entered into the `filter1Text` JTextField that is not numeric will automatically be converted to 0, and a message will be displayed to the user telling them to enter a valid value.

Answer (score -2):

First of all,you can control the empty *TextFields* using the ***trim*** method. This control must be used before you assign textField value to the arraylist.

Before control textField value is empty or not,then assign to the arraylist.

```
 String controlledText = eid.getText().trim();//read contents of text area into 'TextField'
      if(!controlledText.equals("")){

      //doSometing();

      }
```

Comment: His eid.getSite() method return int, so there is no way of using trim() on it.

Comment: **eid.getText()** method returns String format. I did not write **eid.getSite()**